# How to customize the outgoing animation depending on the next route?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

## What I want:

My scene is divided in 2 parts: the button bar and the content. I want something similar to the Android ViewPager behavior: When I tap one button, the corresponding scene is sliding in from the left or the right, depending of the button position in the button bar:

```
 ______________________________
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|______________________________|
|          |          |        |
| Discover | TV Shows | Movies |
|__________|__________|________|
```

For example, when navigating from **Discover** to **TV Shows**, the **TV Shows** scene should slide from the right and simultaneously the **Discover** scene should move out to the left.

Note that the intermediate item **TV Shows** can have different transitions depending where we come from:

- from **Discover** to **TV Shows** --> the **TV Shows** scene should come from the right
- from **Movies** to **TV Shows** --> the **TV Shows** scene should come from the left

## What I did:

I created my own PageRoute where I override the `buildTransitions` method. I have a bit of logic to determine the direction of the slide animation:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomPageRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
  final String currentTab;
  final String newTab;
  final Widget child;

  CustomPageRoute(this.currentTab, this.newTab, this.child) : super(builder: (BuildContext context) => child);

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    if (currentTab == null) {
      // First scene of the Navigator, use the theme (FadeTransition)
      return super.buildTransitions(context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child);
    }

    Offset startPosition;
    switch ('$currentTab-->$newTab') {
      case '/-->/tvshow':
      case '/-->/movie':
      case '/tvshow-->/movie':
        // If the button is on the right in the tab bar, the scene will come from the right
        startPosition = Offset(1.0, 0.0);
        break;
      case '/tvshow-->/':
      case '/movie-->/':
      case '/movie-->/tvshow':
        // If the button is on the left in the tab bar, the scene will come from the left
        startPosition = Offset(-1.0, 0.0);
        break;
      default:
        startPosition = Offset.zero;
    }

    return SlideTransition(
      position: Tween<Offset>(
        begin: startPosition,
        end: Offset.zero,
      ).animate(animation),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Usage in the `onGenerateRoute` of my `Navigator`:

```dart
onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
  Widget widget;

  switch (settings.name) {
    case '/':
      widget = DiscoverTab();
      break;
    case '/tvshow':
      widget = TvShowTab();
      break;
    case '/movie':
      widget = MovieTab();
      break;
    default:
      throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
  }

  CustomPageRoute route = CustomPageRoute(this.lastRoute, settings.name, widget);
  // Save the route for the next one
  this.lastRoute = settings.name;

  return route;
}
```

## The problem:

The incoming scene is coming from the correct side (left of right), but the outgoing scene stays in place. So the incoming scene is "covering" the outgoing scene.

The look and feel is not that bad, however it is not the desired result:

**I want the outgoing scene to move out the screen in the opposite direction to leave the place to the incoming scene** like a real slider. So I have to animate the outgoing scene as well with the `secondaryAnimation` argument.

I can compose the 2 animations, like that:

```dart
SlideTransition(
  position: new Tween<Offset>(
    begin: Offset(1.0, 0.0),
    end: Offset.zero,
  ).animate(animation), // Incoming scene from right
  child: new SlideTransition(
    position: new Tween<Offset>(
      begin: Offset.zero,
      end: Offset(-1.0, 0.0),
    ).animate(secondaryAnimation), // Outgoing scene to the left
    child: child,
  ),
);
```

It will work **EXCEPT** for the intermediate **TV shows** scene because it can have 2 different transitions depending of the next route: the direction is not known at the time of route creation. It will be known only when the next route will be created.

So my question is: When creating a new route, is it possible to access to the current route's outgoing transition definition and redefine it?

My best clue is a `_updateSecondaryAnimation` method called by `didChangeNext` in the [TransitionRoute](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/cb906179117a0d585bd79e43ac0e5568ef488ca6/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart#L218-L224) class, but I can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: Ever thought about using a PageView and handling the Page Transitions via the page Controller?